# How to simplify these compound logical expression?

Tags: c, boolean-algebra

How to simplify these compound logical expressions?

```
!((x <= 5) && (y == 10) && (z < 5))  // 1
!(x == 10) || !((y == 5) || (z < 0)) // 2
```

I have read the rule for simplification, but I am not understanding what to do with `==`.

This is from "Programing in ANSI C" written by E Balagurasy
While designing decision statements, we often come across a situation where the logical NOT operator is applied to a compound logical expression, like !(x&&y || !z). However,a positive logic is always easy to read and comprehend than a negative logic. In such cases, we may apply what is known as De Morgan's rule to make the total expression positive.The rule is as follows: "Remove the parentheses by applying the NOT operator to every logical expression component, while complementing the relational operators." Example: !(x&&y || !z) becomes !x || !y && z.

Comment: I am guessing you want the negation normal form? The opposite of `==` is `!=`, by the way. I don't understand what you mean by "where there is no parentheses". I don't see anywhere where there are none.

Comment: The first step would be to add some whitespace to make the expressions more readable. The next step is to show us exactly what you've done so far.

Comment: some kind of. Me and my friends nedd it for assignment and class test.

Comment: so you are saying that !(x==10) will be !x!=10 ??@Tim

Comment: No `!(x==10)` is `x!=10`  You are going to have to be more specific with your question though. There is no canonical definition of simpler. Your teacher probably asked you to do a specific thing I am guessing?

Comment: While designing decision statements, we often come across a situation where the logical NOT operator is applied to a compound logical expression, like !(x&&y || !z). However,a positive logic is always easy to read and comprehend than a negative logic. In such cases, we may apply what is known as De Morgan's rule to make the total expression positive.The rule is as follows: "Remove the parentheses by applying the NOT operator to every logical expression component, while complementing the relational operators." Example: !(x&&y || !z) becomes !x || !y && z. This is from "Programing in ANSI C"@Tim

Comment: Ok, then you do want the negation normal form. Taylor's answer should help you then. If it helped you, you should consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you some hints, so as to not do your homework for you:

`!(a || b || c) = (!a && !b && !c)`

`!(a && b && c) = (!a || !b || !c)`

`!(a == b) = (a != b)`

`!(a <= b) = (a > b)`

You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Than you for your answer. I got it. Thanks for the help